# Tableau - How to replace data source for only one sheet

Tags: tableau-api

I am pulling data for a couple brands into google sheets with zapier. I am pulling information from each sheet as a separate data source in tableau. The formatting across the sheets is uniform, only values are different.

My objective is to use a completed viz sheet as a template, so that I can duplicate the sheet, and replace the data source. However I am running into a problem.

Generally when replacing a data source with "replace data source" the changes occur on a project wide level, but I need the changes to occur on a sheet level.

Is there any way to hook a viz sheet into a different data source, assuming the data source has the same formatting as "template" file?

Comment: wouldn't format copy-paster and custom color-palette solve this?

Answer (score 7):

When I need to replace a data source of just one sheet, I copy and paste that sheet into a new workbook. Replace it there, and copy and paste it back to my original workbook.

Comment: Brilliant! Not sure if the best way, but it sure works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick look on google brought up this: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1156

It shows first that there is no "Replace source for current sheet"function as such but also gives a workaround for that:

1. Create bookmark (details: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_savework_bookmarks.html)
2. Rename original datasource
3. Re-import bookmark
4. This creates a second instance of the data source for the bookmarked sheet
5. Change the newly created datasource which is only used on one sheet